# Can Firebase Cloud Messaging platform be used to send messages to Java SE receivers/clients?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We're looking for a solution that enables us to communicate from our app servers (Java) via Firebase Cloud Messaging (or, I suppose some similar platform) to our Java SE-based client software. Those clients are running on desktop computers.

I've done this from our servers=>android, and realize that mobile is the intended use case for Firebase, but has anyone tried something similar? Can it be done?
Can anyone point me in the direction of some resources to guide me?

Or possibly suggest alternative push technology?

Comment: I'm not aware of any non-Android Java receiver for Firebase Cloud Messaging. An alternative push technology could be the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). But recommending that is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen ! I ran into the same problem though, with the Firebase Realtime Database being first and foremost targeted towards mobile. Currently I'm looking into Server-Sent Events (SSE) that seem promising!