# Receive push notifications on a Java Cross Platform Desktop app

Tags: java, maven, firebase, javafx, push-notification

I'm developing a Java Desktop App, using Javafx and I'm trying to receive push notifications from a server. My first approach was to use firebase. I already connected to firebase and even achieve, for test purpose, storing data in firebase database. But the goal I really need is to receive push notifications.

I'm using firebase-admin:6.5.0, but this module doesn't provide me the FirebaseMessagingService class that I need to receive notifications.

I also tried to use firebase-messaging but appear with an error underline after de import.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? It´s even possible to receive push notifications in a Java Desktop app with firebase? What alternative do I have?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no SDK to **receive** Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications in a Java client. Consider using another technology to deliver the notifications, such as the Firebase Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore.

The Admin SDK you use grants fill administrative access to your entire Firebase project. It is meant for use on *trusted environments*, such as your development machine, or a server you control.

Also see:

- [Can Firebase Cloud Messaging platform be used to send messages to Java SE receivers/clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877358/can-firebase-cloud-messaging-platform-be-used-to-send-messages-to-java-se-receiv)
- [Is that possible for Win32/64 application to receive push notification message from Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537377/is-that-possible-for-win32-64-application-to-receive-push-notification-message-f)
- [Can we use FireBase cloud Messaging to send or receive messages or both ways using C++ on Windows Desktop/Console or Linux console appliction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229503/can-we-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-to-send-or-receive-messages-or-both-ways-usi)

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your reply. I'm trying to use Firebase Realtime Database. I can insert and retrieve data but is possible to have a listener to detect when data is updated

Comment: Yes. If you add a listener with `addChildEventListener` or `addValueEventListener` it should be called for the current data *and* for subsequent changes. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-types. If that doesn't work, you might want to post a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

ControlsFX provides the GUI support for notification [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/)